# model class data Retriving

Tags: ios

I have implemented a UITableview in ViewController1 and retrieving the data from JSON. I Want to display the cell with the Image,Tittle and Sub tittle.I am using a TableClass as model class for that

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


NSURLSession*session=[NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=music"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);

    NSArray*entryarr=[json objectForKey:@"results"];

    TableClass*tc=[[TableClass alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary*appDict in entryarr) {


        NSString*str=[appDict objectForKey:@"artistName"];
        [tc setTittle:str];

        NSLog(@"artist Name=%@",tc.tittle);

        //setting Subtittle
        NSString*sub=[appDict objectForKey:@"country"];

        [tc setSubtittle:sub];

        NSLog(@"artist Name=%@",tc.subtittle);



        NSString*imageStr=[appDict objectForKey:@"artworkUrl60"];
        [tc setImage:imageStr];

        NSURL*imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr];




        NSData*imageData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];



      [self.imageArray addObject:imageData];

        [_tableArray addObject:tc];

        NSLog(@"%@ name of tittle",[_tableArray objectAtIndex:0]);




    }

    NSLog(@"%lu %lu %lu",(unsigned long)self.tableArray.count,(unsigned long)self.tableArray.count,(unsigned long)self.tableArray.count);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];    
[dataTask resume];

});

}
```

But Now i display the data By

```
cell.textLabel.text=[[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"_tittle"];


cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"_subtittle"];

cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"_image"]];
```

But I feel that method is not optimise, So I want to display Data through Model class itself How can i do it...?

Comment: yes but i want it by Model class

Comment: you just want to use your model class in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method right ?

Comment: Yes how can i do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TableClass.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TableClass : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *subtittle;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *imageURL;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSData *imageData;

@end
```

in your `ViewController.m`

```
-(void)getData
{

    NSURLSession*session=[NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=music"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);

        NSArray*entryarr=[json objectForKey:@"results"];

        self.tableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSDictionary*appDict in entryarr)
        {

            TableClass *classModel=[[TableClass alloc]init];
            classModel.title=[appDict objectForKey:@"artistName"];
            classModel.subtittle=[appDict objectForKey:@"country"];
            classModel.imageURL=[appDict objectForKey:@"artworkUrl60"];
            classModel.imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:classModel.imageURL]];
            [self.tableArray addObject:classModel];

        }

        NSLog(@"%lu %lu %lu",(unsigned long)self.tableArray.count,(unsigned long)self.tableArray.count,(unsigned long)self.tableArray.count);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //update UI in main thread.
            [self.myTableView reloadData];
        });

    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return self.tableArray.count;
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]    initWithStyle:
                UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    TableClass *tableclassModel=[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=tableclassModel.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=tableclassModel.subtittle;
    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:tableclassModel.imageData]];

    return cell;
}
```

In this example you don't need an extra array to store images.
Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: but now i am not able to retrieve image

Comment: i am only getting the Last item  in that array

Comment: @Cyph3r are you still facing problem ?